# Display data in a spinner from arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, spinner

I have 2 activity classes, "Inset_plate_number" class and "CarSelection" class. What I was trying to write something in the text boxes in "Insert_plate_number" class and then put what I have written into a ArrayList and then store in sharedpreferences. Next, I want to retrieve the things that I stored in sharedpreferences and display them in a spinner in "CarSelection" class.

But everytime I run it, it gives me NullPointerException error. Is there something wrong with the arraylist, storing sharedpreferences, loading shared preferences or displaying on spinner?

Insert_plate_number class,

```
public class Insert_plate_number extends ActionBarActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> list;
    static SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    static String combo;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPREFERENCES";
    static int size;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_insert_plate_number);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void onClick_Save(View view) {
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        EditText plate_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car_plate_number);
        EditText phone_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        String phoneNo = phone_number.getText().toString();
        String plateNo = plate_number.getText().toString(); 
        combo = plateNo + "," + phoneNo;
        list.add(combo);
        size = list.size();
        editor.putInt("list_size", size);   
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            editor.putString("list_"+i, list.get(i));
        }
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

CarSelection class,

```
public class CarSelection extends ActionBarActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_car_selection);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Insert_plate_number.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int arraysize = sharedpreferences.getInt("list_size", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i <arraysize; i++) {
            sharedpreferences.getString("list_"+i, null);
        }       
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CarSelection.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Insert_plate_number.list);
        adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 979
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.CarSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:114)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:413)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.example.myfirstapp.CarSelection.onCreate(CarSelection.java:33)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-07 12:52:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is on line 33 in CarSelection.java ?

Comment: What is line 33 at CarSelection.java?

Comment: What is the point of calling `sharedpreferences.getString("list_"+i, null);` if you are not storing the returned string in anywhere?

Comment: You are not creating the adapter using the element you have fetched from shared preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are trying to access an ArrayList of another class that might be null.

The best way to achieve what you want is doing this in your CarSelection.class in onCreate:

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Insert_plate_number.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// You need to create an Array list and fill it with string you have in SharedPreferences
ArrayList<String> list;       
list = new ArrayList<String>();
int arraysize = sharedpreferences.getInt("list_size", 0);
for (int i = 0; i <arraysize; i++) {        
    list.add(sharedpreferences.getString("list_"+i, ""));
}

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well now. But I'm facing another problem, whenever I add a new text into the arraylist, the spinner display only the new text and all my previous texts have been removed, any idea with it?

Comment: I found the solution. My arraylist in the onCreate was empty initially, so I get all the previous added data from sharedpreferences and add into the empty arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

sharedpreferences.getString("list_"+i, null); change the null this causes the error..